# Questions regarding reorganizing loops for code's efficiency

Tags: matlab

Here's the problem

Consider the following function:

```
function A = plodding(N,d)
for ii = 1:N
   jj = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      jj = jj + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
```

Rewrite this function to eliminate the allocation problem that is slowing it down. Call the new function, cruising. On a Dell Latitude E6410, with 7.8 gigabytes of usable memory, eliminating the allocation problem produces a speed-up factor of 7.

Here's my work:

The original version with rng(0)

```
function A = plodding(N,d)
rng(0); % To compare between the original and the modified version
for ii = 1:N
   jj = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      jj = jj + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
end
```

The modified version

```
function A = cruising(N,d)
rng(0);
for jj = 1:N % Reorganize, so elems are added column-wise
   ii = 1;
   A(ii,jj) = randn;
   while abs(A(ii,jj)) < d
      ii = ii + 1;
      A(ii,jj) = randn;
   end
end
A = A'; % To get the matrix desired
end
```

But when I test:

```
tic; A = plodding(5,4.5); toc
Elapsed time is 0.176091 seconds.

tic; A1 = cruising(5,4.5); toc;
Elapsed time is 39.285447 seconds.

B = A - A1; sum(B(:))
ans = 0
```

So certainly `A = A1`

Based on what I learned from the lesson, my logic should be right, because MATLAB stores elements column-wise. Could someone please help me????

Comment: Are you sure you weren't supposed to try preallocate some memory for `A`? You may not know the exact dimensions, but based on `d` you can calculate the probability of the number of columns per row and then allocate such that this doesn't extend very often (say a 95% chance or something)

Comment: @Dan: I understand what you said, yet I don't really know how to do that. I've thought about having a large matrix of 0s and then truncate the extra 0s that I threw in (but not sure how...)
Regardless, I don't really know why my modified version is much slower, because like I said, MATLAB stores everything in column-wise. So my modified version should work much better than the original version.

Comment: Well I've never heard the assertion that Matlab is more efficient columnwise. Indeed, your own test data appears to debunk it yourself. Do you have a source?

Comment: But that behaviour aside, @Dan is right; you've misinterpreted the task you've been set. Pretty much every iteration of the loop is increasing the size of the array. You need to come up with a solution where you create a blank array which already has space allocated and fill the elements (pre-allocated)

Comment: @MattTaylor Matlab stores data in a column-major fashion (think how the linear indexing is arranged). This means if you have an `n` element row vector and add a column to it, Matlab just has to create `n` `0`s contiguously in memory. If you had a row vector and add a column then it has to create `n` `0`s again but this time it has to intersperse each between each element that is already in the matrix. This should be more computationally expensive, I think that is what the OP is implying. I'm not sure what's going wrong in this particular case though...

Comment: @Dan and to all: Please look at this result to understand what I'm asking `>> tic;A = plodding(10000,2);toc
Elapsed time is 9.289355 seconds.
>> tic;A1 = cruising(10000,2);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.078783 seconds.
>> tic;A = plodding(5,5);toc
Elapsed time is 1.168961 seconds.
>> tic;A1 = cruising(5,5);toc;
% When I posted this thread, it's already more than 10 mins and MATLAB's still "busy"!` Based on what I learned, cruising should perform faster than plodding in ANY case . This behavior of MATLAB suggests that there's something about it that I still don't quite grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Allocation

The differences are more than likely arising from when and how often Matlab has to reallocate the dynamically growing matrix.
Consider the following output:

```
>> clear();n = 1E5;A = rand(n,1);tic;for k = 2:500; A(:,k) = rand(n,1);end;toc;whos();
Elapsed time is 1.294744 seconds.
  Name           Size                 Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         100000x500            400000000  double              
  k              1x1                      8  double              
  n              1x1                      8  double              

>> clear();n = 1E5;A = rand(1,n);tic;for k = 2:500; A(k,:) = rand(1,n);end;toc;whos();
Elapsed time is 31.106700 seconds.
  Name        Size                    Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         500x100000            400000000  double              
  k           1x1                         8  double              
  n           1x1                         8  double
```

Despite growing the array `A` to the same size, growing it column-wise is nearly 25 times faster.
Since Matlab is a column-major language, the columns of its arrays are always contiguous in memory.
So in the second loop, Matlab needs to reallocate every expanded column to a contiguous section of memory at the beginning of every iteration, which can have a huge overhead.
Whereas, in the first loop, Matlab can address the new column right after the previous one, if space exists, or add a pointer connecting the end of the previous column to the new, if Matlab supports non-contiguous arrays (I don't know anything about Matlab internals, but I'd lean toward this method).

The function `plodding` grows column-wise (inner) then row-wise (outer) while `cruising` grows row-wise (inner) then grows column-wise.
The running time differences depend on these two allocation methodologies but also on the condition used to terminate the allocation (i.e., the threshold value `d`).

### Probability

The probability of receiving a number less than or equal to `d` is calculated from the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Examples) of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).
This can be calculated using the Statistics Toolbox's [`normcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) or, if you do not have the toolbox, the following anonymous function:

```
normcdf = @(x,mu,sigma) 0.5*(1 + erf((x-mu)./(sigma*sqrt(2))));
```

The probability of receiving a 2 or less is `normcdf(2,0,1)` which is 97.7%, and the probability of receiving a value higher than 2 is one minus the probability: `1 - normcdf(2,0,1)` or 2.28%.
The probabilities can be used to estimate the number of elements in an array needed to get a number greater than `d`.
For example, since there is a 2.28% chance of getting a value greater than 2, an array of 100 elements will more than likely produce at about two 2s on average.

For another example, the probability of getting a number greater than 5 is 0.000029%, and that means that an array of around 1 million elements is needed to get some 5s on average.
Note that the formula I used to estimate the array size is

```
elemApprox = 10^(abs(log10(1 - normcdf(5,0,1))))
```

and then I divide it by the significant digits of the probability (2.8665 in this case) to get a rough estimate for the approximate number of elements to get one 5.
It doesn't hurt to approximate like this since we are dealing with random numbers.
For more certainty, you can always multiply the guess by 2 or 3 or more.

### Results Discussion

Now let's discuss the results you got.  From the comments, you presented

```
>> tic;A = plodding(10000,2);toc
Elapsed time is 9.289355 seconds.
>> tic;A1 = cruising(10000,2);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.078783 seconds.
```

As discussed above, the array will have dimensions of 10,000 by about 100 (due to 2's probability).
The call `plodding(10000,2)` will then generate about 100 columns for its first iteration, and then grow the array row-wise for 10,000 iterations.
As discussed above, that is a very slow process in Matlab and best avoided if possible.
The call `cruising(10000,2)` will then generate about 100 rows for its first iteration, and then grow the array column-wise for 10,000 iterations.
As discussed above, this is a far faster process than row-wise growth for **constant row length** but can be extremely slow in certain cases.

You also posted the results:

```
>> tic;A = plodding(5,5);toc
Elapsed time is 1.168961 seconds.
>> tic;A1 = cruising(5,5);toc;
% When I posted this thread, it's already more than 10 mins and MATLAB's still "busy"!
```

The call `plodding(5,5)` will generate about 1,000,000 columns for its first iteration, and then grow the array row-wise for 5 iterations.
So after every successful inner-loop, Matlab must reallocate 1 million or-so 5 64-bit columns into contiguous memory slots.
While not necessarily fast, finding a million separate locations of 40 bytes probably isn't the worst thing in the world with modern memory sizes.
The call `cruising(5,5)` will generate about 1,000,000 rows for its first iteration, and then grow the array column-wise for 5 iterations.
This appears better than the `plodding` call since the rows are being allocated first and then columns added; however, if the number of required rows for subsequent iterations is greater than the current row count, the array's columns must be reallocated after **every** inner-iteration until the break condition is met.

Diving a little deeper, the first iteration (on my computer) of `cruising(5,5)` takes about 2.8 seconds to run and allocates 756,670 rows.
The second iteration takes about 2.6 seconds to iterate over the allocated rows, and after waiting for 60 seconds past that point, the second iteration has only advanced 20,366 rows.
I would conclude that the repeated addition of rows and making Matlab re-allocate about 6MB contiguous blocks of memory per-column makes the function extremely slow.

### Recommendation

My recommendation for performance improvement would be to allocate the number of rows of `A` before entering the loop.
For `plodding`, this means adding `A(N,elemApprox) = 0;` before the loop, and for `cruising`, this means adding `A(elemApprox,N) = 0;` before the loop. `elemApprox` is the approximate number of rows/columns needed to consistently achieve the condition without growing the array.

Even though I approximated `elemApprox` to be 1,000,000 earlier for `d = 5`, it turns out that maximum number of rows with `rng(0)` specified is 3,151,807.
Therefore, for a consistent upper bound on `elemApprox`, I'd amend the above approximation formula to be

```
elemApprox = 10^(ceil(abs(log10(1 - normcdf(5,0,1)))));
```

which is 10,000,000.  That's a little steep if memory is limited, but it will greatly increase the running time.
Using the allocation formula, the performance of `cruising` is greatly improved:

```
>> tic;plodding(5,5);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.576764 seconds.
>> tic;cruising(5,5);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.906496 seconds.
```

I'm not sure why `plodding` is performing better, but at least `cruising` now completes in a reasonable amount of time.

I'd also like to point out that adding just `A(N,1) = 0` to `plodding` and letting Matlab know how many rows there will be results in a large performance gain for small `d`:

```
>> tic;plodding(1E4,2);toc; %   without A(N,1) = 0;
Elapsed time is 18.479698 seconds.
>> tic;plodding(1E4,2);toc; %   WITH A(N,1) = 0;
Elapsed time is 0.052307 seconds.
```